# Отмена события при обратном щелчке мыши

Tags: jquery

При наведении указателя мыши объект появляется, при отведении указателя мыши объект удаляется. Применил функцию off чтобы, при нажатии объект не удалялся при отведении мыши. Как сделать чтобы при обратном щелчке вновь объект удалился и работал как прежде? https://jsfiddle.net/zb9q7e8b/2/

```js
  $('h2').next().hide();

  $('h2').mouseover(function() {
    var $anse = $(this).next();
    $anse.show();
  });
  $('h2').mouseout(function() {
    var $anse = $(this).next();
    $anse.hide();
  });
  $('h2').click(function() {
    var $anse = $(this).next();
    $(this).off('mouseout');
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h2>123</h2>
<div>333</div>
<h2>123</h2>
<div>333</div>
<h2>123</h2>
<div>333</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно сделать через добавление-удаление класса `offed`, если класса нет, то добавляем его и применяем `off()`, а если класс есть, то удаляем его и добавляем событие `mouseout()`:

```js
var titles = $('h2');

titles.next('div').hide();

titles.mouseover(function() {
  $(this).next('div').show();
});

titles.mouseout(function() {
  $(this).next('div').hide();
});

titles.click(function() {
  if (!$(this).hasClass('offed')) {
    $(this).off('mouseout').addClass('offed');
  } else {
    $(this).mouseout(function() {
      $(this).next('div').hide();
    });
    $(this).removeClass('offed');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h2>123</h2>
<div>333</div>
<h2>123</h2>
<div>333</div>
<h2>123</h2>
<div>333</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Еще один вариант на классах:

```js
$('h2').on('mouseover mouseout click', function(e) {
  var $anse = $(this).next();
  if (e.type == 'click') {
    $anse.toggleClass('clicked');
  } else {
    if (!$anse.hasClass('clicked')) {
      $anse.toggleClass('hovered');
    }
  }
});
```

```css
div {
  display: none;
}

div.clicked,
div.hovered {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h2>123</h2>
<div>333</div>
<h2>123</h2>
<div>333</div>
<h2>123</h2>
<div>333</div>
```

**Update**

В случаи если у пользователя не работает `JS` можно `hover` на `css` сделать.

```js
$('h2').on('click', function(e) {
  $(this).next().toggleClass('clicked');
});
```

```css
div {
  display: none;
}

h2:hover + div {
  display: block;
} 

div.clicked {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h2>123</h2>
<div>333</div>
<h2>123</h2>
<div>333</div>
<h2>123</h2>
<div>333</div>
```

Comment: Но есть вероятность что у пользователя не будет работать JS, и тогда у них не будет возможности увидеть блок

Comment: @PeGaS, обновил ответ!

Comment: @PeGaS, не отключает сейчас никто JS, вероятность отключённого JS стремится к нулю, да и 99,5% сайтов без JS не будут работать

Comment: @Ihor Tkachuk, вариант интересный, но плохо расширяемый, в реальности лучше каждому событию делать отдельную функцию, чтобы при добавлении функционала не пришлось ломать голову, как его увязать с такой логикой